# How to Grab an Icon Image

Tags: html, css, image, screen-grab

I was browsing different websites for some images that I'd like to use for links. One, for example, is a Twitter image.

Normally you can hover over an image and press "control + click" to save as.

But on this particular website, the images are icons and don't allow me to grab them.

Here is a screen of select element which the image I want highlighted, and the html and css that goes with it.

How would I grab this icon? The icons are on this website: https://uchaguzi.co.ke/

[image]

Comment: Somewhere in the CSS it's likely referencing an image file.  (Though it's also possible that this is a custom font and not an image.)  Check the Network tab and see what files have been requested by the page.

Comment: indeed, it really seems a font awesome icon (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/twitter/). If you like it you may take a screenshoot of it.

the letter used by the icon is defined in the css file in this way:
`.icon-twitter:before {
content: "\e00c";
}`

Comment: David could not see anything in Network tab but thanks anyway. Furins that looks promising I'll have a browse around. If all the icons from the site I want to swipe from are on there it's be great. That site and my own are both crowdmaps with similar functionality so their icons are relevant to my site too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert Font Awesome icons to png, you may use this software:
https://github.com/odyniec/font-awesome-to-png

however... if *fontawesome* fits your needs (it has a huge collection of really well-designed icons), I warmly suggest you to use the web font as explained here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Comment: I went back unnaccepted. Your response was useful, I just want to keep it open a while to see if anyone knows if it's possible to grab an icon in the same way that you could grab a standard image, such as a png

Comment: Sure, no problem... but no, it's not possible to grab a font icon like it was a standard image (like from a dropdown menu in your browser) except using a software to capture part of the screen. For instance with MAC OS you may use CMD+SHIFT+4 to capture part of the screen and save it as a png, in WINDOWS (any version) you may use CTRL+ALT+PRINT and then paste the content of the clipboard into a software to manipulate images (eventually you may even use `paint`), in order to crop it to the desired size.